# Whether two linearly dependent vector fields can be linearly represented by a third vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry

Given to linearly dependent vector fields $X$ and $Y$ on a maniflold $M$, i.e., there exist two non-vanishing functions $f,g:M\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $fX+gY\equiv0$, is there a third vector field $Z$ such that both $X$ and $Y$ can be linearly represented by $Z$, i.e., are there functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $X=\alpha Z$ and $Y=\beta Z$?

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ non-vanishing or non-identically-vanishing?

Comment: Clearly if at least one on the functions (say $f$) is non-vanishing then $X = -\frac gf Y$.

Comment: non-identically-vanishing@Didier

Comment: both $f$ and $g$ could vanishing at some points, it is better to say that $X$ and $Y$ are point-wise parallel I think.@PaulSinclair

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got an solution, the vector field $Z$ can be defined as follows
\begin{equation*}
Z=\begin{cases}
X/g&\text{if } g\ne 0\\
-Y/f&\text{if } f\ne 0\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}